# Jquery .prepend() keeps one element at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, prepend

I'm having this problem where the Jquery .prepend works fine, except the first element in an array is kept at the top of the page at all times. Basically I want to loop through a bunch of objects stored in an array where the newest object is stored at the end and I want the newest object at the very top of the page.

I have this in javascript right now:

```
function post(descript, title, username, id){

  this.descript = descript,
  this.title = title,
  this.username = username,
  this.id = id

  $("#descript").html(descript);
  $("#title").html(title);
  $("#username").html(username);
  $post = $("#template").clone();
  $post.attr("id", id);
  $(".feed_div").prepend($post);
  $post.fadeIn();
};

var data = [oldest, older, old, new, newer, newest];
for (i in data) {
    var obj = data[i];
    new post(obj.text, obj.title, obj.username, obj.id);
};
```

And then in html, it looks like:

```
<div class="feed_div">
  <div class = "post" id="template" style="display:none">
    <h2>
      <span id="title"></span>
      <span id="username"></span>
    </h2>
    <p id="descript"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything displays exactly how I want it to, but no matter what I do, the first element in the array always stays at the top. So the page always has an order of:

oldest,
newest,
newer,
new,
old,
older

Can anyone figure this out?

Here is a link to an editable jsfiddle so you can see what's happening:

https://jsfiddle.net/azgmqdo4/

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle please

Comment: First off, you html is invalid as you're generating elements with duplicate IDs. You would be better of using classes. Did you mean your order becomes `newest, newer, new, old, older, oldest` ?

Comment: And @LShetty I think I just copied my structure wrong so I edited the id part of the feed_div out. It works fine and everything does exactly what it should. The only thing wrong with it is that after the for loop iterates through the first object in the array, the .prepend function prepends each object to the second position on the page instead of the first. So, the order is fine EXCEPT the order is: oldest, newest, new, old, older, oldest. It pins the first object in the array at the top and everything else under that is fine

Comment: @jcbartlett25 http://jsfiddle.net/ Please provide us with a reproducible example of the issue. You shouldn't be using `for..in` to iterate through a loop. The order is not guaranteed. And why are you using `new` to call a function and assigning values to `this` that you never use?

Comment: @jcbartlett25 You still have a problem in that you are referring to elements by the IDs `descript`, `title`, etc. And creating copies of those elements. As LShetty has already said, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @JLRishe thank you so much for helping, I'm obviously new to this website. But I think I added the jsfiddle correctly. I'm using post as a constructor for the post object. I'm not following the whole ID situation though, should each element in the html have a dynamically created id?

Comment: @BradleyWilson I included a link to the jsfiddle

Comment: @jcbartlett25 _"should each element in the html have a dynamically created id"_ No, they don't have to have IDs at all, but if you give them IDs, they should not be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're getting the result you're getting, but it is most likely due to your use of duplicate IDs.

As I alluded in the comments (and a few additional suggestions):

- Don't use duplicate IDs
- Don't use `new` if you're not actually constructing anything
- Don't use a constructor as a side-effect to modify the DOM
- Don't use `for..in` to iterate over arrays
- Modify an item *after* you have cloned it, not before
- Don't use `.html()` unless you actually have some HTML to display

Once these issues are fixed, it appears to work as expected:

```js
function addPost(descript, title, username, id) {
    $post = $("#template").clone();
    $post.attr("id", id);
    $post.find(".descript").text(descript);
    $post.find(".title").text(title);
    $post.find(".username").text(username);
    $(".feed_div").prepend($post);
    $post.fadeIn();
}
//creating objects
var oldest = {
    title: "oldest",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 1
};

var older = {
    title: "older",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 2
};

var old = {
    title: "old",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 3
};

var new1 = {
    title: "new",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 4
};

var newer = {
    title: "newer",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 5
};

var newest = {
    title: "newest",
    text: "blah",
    username: "blah2",
    id: 6
};

var data = [oldest, older, old, new1, newer, newest];

data.forEach(function (obj) {
    addPost(obj.text, obj.title, obj.username, obj.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="feed_div">
        <div class="post" id="template" style="display:none">
             <h2>
                 <span class="title"></span>
                 <span class="username"></span>
            </h2>

            <p class="descript"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```